# How to edit local variable values in windbg command line interface?

Tags: python, windbg

I'm integrating python with windbg and I want to edit a local variable value from the script. For that I need to know how to edit local variable values in windbg command line.

I know I can get value by variable, but how to edit the same variable?

Comment: What you did till now? What is your code?

Comment: Say I hit a function and I get values of variable XYZ as 1000 by using ??XYZ. Now I want to edit the same variable to 2000, how can I do it in windbg CLI? Is that possible?

Comment: Believe it or not, this is as simple as: `?? XYZ = 2000`.

Comment: a local wont be initialised when on function entry.   when are you evaluating the local?? . An assign to the local will only be effective after its initial initialisation has occured within the function scope

Comment: @lebellinoz please revert back to ??variable  and may be highlight it it is a windbg specific expression and not a typo it is c++ expression evaluator  not a double question mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [described on MSDN for `??`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/----evaluate-c---expression-):

> ?? *Expression*

and looking up the [linked C++ numbers and operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/c---numbers-and-operators):

> LValue = Value         Assign

you can simply

```
?? <variable name> = <value>
```

As an alternative, you can also use the `e*` commands to [edit values in memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/e--ea--eb--ed--ed--ef--ep--eq--eu--ew--eza--ezu--enter-values-), e.g.

```
eb <address> <byte1> <byte2>
```

Comment: Thanks..this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i commented but the comment grew long so posting it as an answer

a local won't be initialized when on function entry.
when are you evaluating the local?? . 
An assign to the local will only be effective after its initial initialization has occurred within the function scope 
and prior to its usage

you can assign to the local as suggested by Sean Cline using the c++ expression evaluator but it is very important you have the exact location

assume you have code like this

```
:\>cat localedit.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
int addme(int a , int b) {
    int c = 25; int d = c*3;int e = a*c;int f = d*b;
    return c+d+e+f;
}
void main (void) {
    printf("%d\n" , addme( 50,50));
}
:\>
```

if you execute this under windbg and reach the addme() and assigned some value to local c on the function entry it would be not be effective at all

see below

```
0:000> r

localedit!addme:
003d1000 55              push    ebp
0:000> dv
              a = 0n50
              b = 0n50
              d = 0n0
              c = 0n4121264
              f = 0n1308704
              e = 0n4002235
0:000> ?? c
int 0n4121264

0:000> ?? c = 100
int 0n100

0:000> ?? c
int 0n100
0:000> g
5100   <<<<<< see the result is same as executing without modification 

0:000> q
quit:

:\>localedit.exe
5100 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

complete disassembly of function addme

```
0:000> uf .
localedit!addme:
01341000 55              push    ebp
01341001 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
01341003 83ec10          sub     esp,10h
01341006 c745fc19000000  mov     dword ptr [ebp-4],19h
0134100d 6b45fc03        imul    eax,dword ptr [ebp-4],3
01341011 8945f8          mov     dword ptr [ebp-8],eax
01341014 8b4d08          mov     ecx,dword ptr [ebp+8]
01341017 0faf4dfc        imul    ecx,dword ptr [ebp-4]
0134101b 894df4          mov     dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],ecx
0134101e 8b55f8          mov     edx,dword ptr [ebp-8]
01341021 0faf550c        imul    edx,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]
01341025 8955f0          mov     dword ptr [ebp-10h],edx
01341028 8b45fc          mov     eax,dword ptr [ebp-4]
0134102b 0345f8          add     eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]
0134102e 0345f4          add     eax,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]
01341031 0345f0          add     eax,dword ptr [ebp-10h]
01341034 8be5            mov     esp,ebp
01341036 5d              pop     ebp
01341037 c3              ret
```

we are at the function entry

```
0:000> r @eip
eip=01341000

we can check what is the address of local c 
and may be write there but unless we step until 
01341006 c745fc19000000  mov     dword ptr [ebp-4],19h

what ever we write will be overwritten again 


0:000> ?? &c
int * 0x0026f7a8

0:000> dd 26f7a8 l1
0026f7a8  0135e2b0

0:000> .enable_long_status 1
0:000> ?? c
int 0x135e2b0


0:000> ?? *(int *)&c = 45
int 0x2d
0:000> ?? c
int 0x2d
0:000> dv
              a = 0x32
              b = 0x32
              d = 0
              c = 0x2d
              f = 0x26f7c0
              e = 0x13411bb
0:000> g
5100
```